# How to add error bars to a grouped bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-science, grouped-bar-chart

I would like to add error bar in my plot that I can show the min max of each plot. Please, anyone can help me. Thanks in advance.

The min max is as follow:

Delay = (53.46 (min 0, max60) , 36.22 (min 12,max 70), 83 (min 21,max 54), 17 (min 12,max 70))
Latency = (38 (min 2,max 70), 44 (min 12,max 87), 53 (min 9,max 60), 10 (min 11,max 77))

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from matplotlib.dates import date2num
import datetime

Delay = (53.46, 36.22, 83, 17)
Latency = (38, 44, 53, 10)
index = ['T=0', 'T=26', 'T=50','T=900']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Delay': Delay, 'Latency': Latency}, index=index)
ax = df.plot.bar(rot=0)
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('(%)')
plt.ylim(0, 101)
plt.savefig('TestX.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In order to plot in the correct location on a bar plot, the patch data for each bar must be extracted.
- An `ndarray` is returned with one [`matplotlib.axes.Axes`](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes) per column.

  - In the case of this figure, `ax.patches` contains 8 [`matplotlib.patches.Rectangle`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html) objects, one for each segment of each bar.

    - By using the associated methods for this object, the `height`, `width`, and `x` locations can be extracted, and used to draw a line with [`plt.vlines`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.vlines.html).
- The `height` of the bar is used to extract the correct `min` and `max` value from `dict`, `z`.

  - Unfortunately, the patch data does not contain the bar label (e.g. `Delay` & `Latency`).
- **Tested in `python 3.11`, `pandas 1.5.3`, `matplotlib 3.7.0`**

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create dataframe
Delay = (53.46, 36.22, 83, 17)
Latency = (38, 44, 53, 10)
index = ['T=0', 'T=26', 'T=50','T=900']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Delay': Delay, 'Latency': Latency}, index=index)

# dicts with errors
Delay_error = {53.46: {'min': 0,'max': 60}, 36.22: {'min': 12,'max': 70}, 83: {'min': 21,'max': 54}, 17: {'min': 12,'max': 70}}
Latency_error = {38: {'min': 2, 'max': 70}, 44: {'min': 12,'max': 87}, 53: {'min': 9,'max': 60}, 10: {'min': 11,'max': 77}}

# combine them; providing all the keys are unique
z = {**Delay_error, **Latency_error}

# plot
ax = df.plot.bar(rot=0)
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('(%)')
plt.ylim(0, 101)

for p in ax.patches:
    x = p.get_x()  # get the bottom left x corner of the bar
    w = p.get_width()  # get width of bar
    h = p.get_height()  # get height of bar
    min_y = z[h]['min']  # use h to get min from dict z
    max_y = z[h]['max']  # use h to get max from dict z
    plt.vlines(x+w/2, min_y, max_y, color='k')  # draw a vertical line
```

[image]

- If there are non-unique values in the two `dicts`, so they can't be combined, we can select the correct `dict` based on the bar plot order.
- All the bars for a single label are plotted first.

  - In this case, index 0-3 are the `Dalay` bars, and 4-7 are the `Latency` bars

```py
for i, p in enumerate(ax.patches):
    print(i, p)
    x = p.get_x()
    w = p.get_width()
    h = p.get_height()
    
    if i < len(ax.patches)/2:  # select which dictionary to use
        d = Delay_error
    else:
        d = Latency_error
        
    min_y = d[h]['min']
    max_y = d[h]['max']
    plt.vlines(x+w/2, min_y, max_y, color='k')
```

Answer (score 0):

Some zipping and stacking will suffice—see `bar_min_maxs` below. Simplifying and slightly generalizing Trenton's code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# create dataframe
Delay = (53.46, 36.22, 83, 17)
Latency = (38, 44, 53, 10)
index = ['T=0', 'T=26', 'T=50','T=900']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Delay': Delay, 'Latency': Latency,
                   'Delay_min':   (0,  12, 21, 12),  # supply min and max
                   'Delay_max':   (60, 70, 54, 70),
                   'Latency_min': (2,  12, 9,  11),
                   'Latency_max': (70, 87, 60, 77)},
                  index=index)

# plot
ax = df[['Delay', 'Latency']].plot.bar(rot=0)
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('(%)')
plt.ylim(0, 101)

# bar_min_maxs[i] is bar/patch i's min, max
bar_min_maxs = np.vstack((list(zip(df['Delay_min'], df['Delay_max'])),
                          list(zip(df['Latency_min'], df['Latency_max']))))
assert len(bar_min_maxs) == len(ax.patches)

for patch, (min_y, max_y) in zip(ax.patches, bar_min_maxs):
    plt.vlines(patch.get_x() + patch.get_width()/2,
               min_y, max_y, color='k')
```

[image: min_max_barplot]

And if errorbars are expressed through margins of errors instead of mins and maxs, i.e., the errorbar is centered at the bar's height w/ length 2 x margin of error, then here's code to plot those:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# create dataframe
Delay = (53.46, 36.22, 83, 17)
Latency = (38, 44, 53, 10)
index = ['T=0', 'T=26', 'T=50','T=900']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Delay': Delay, 'Latency': Latency,
                   'Delay_moe':   (5,  15, 25, 35),  # supply margin of error
                   'Latency_moe': (10, 20, 30, 40)},
                  index=index)

# plot
ax = df[['Delay', 'Latency']].plot.bar(rot=0)
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('(%)')
plt.ylim(0, 101)

# bar_moes[i] is bar/patch i's margin of error, i.e., half the length of an
# errorbar centered at the bar's height
bar_moes = np.ravel(df[['Delay_moe', 'Latency_moe']].values.T)
assert len(bar_moes) == len(ax.patches)

for patch, moe in zip(ax.patches, bar_moes):
    height = patch.get_height() # of bar
    min_y, max_y = height - moe, height + moe
    plt.vlines(patch.get_x() + patch.get_width()/2,
               min_y, max_y, color='k')
```

[image: moe_barplot]

One minor statistical note: if the difference b/t the two groups (Delay and Latency for each T=t) is of interest, then add a plot for the difference with an errorbar for the difference. A plot like the one above is not sufficient for directly analyzing differences; if, e.g., the two errorbars overlap at T=0, this does not imply that the difference b/t Delay and Latency is not statistically significant at whatever level was used. (Though if they don't overlap, then the difference is statistically significant.)